# Returning information in a nested select in the outermost select

Tags: mysql

I've got the following working,

```
SELECT info1, info2 
FROM   TableA 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT xid 
              FROM   TableB 
              WHERE  userid=3 AND active=1)
```

which works fine, but in `TableB` I also have a `team` column which I'd like to select and return in the outermost select statement, something like this "pseudo" query, which of course doesn't work:

```
SELECT info1, info2, team 
FROM   TableA 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT xid, team 
              FROM   TableB 
              WHERE  userid=3 AND active=1)
```

I had a read around and thought maybe `AS` could help but I don't really know for sure. Can anybody suggest a solution? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what `JOIN`s are for:

```
SELECT  A.info1, 
        A.info2, 
        B.team 
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON A.id = B.xid
WHERE B.userid = 3 
AND B.active=1
;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can JOIN both tables in this way:

```
SELECT a.info1, a.info2, b.team 
FROM   TableA a 
JOIN   TableB b
ON     a.id = b.xid
WHERE  b.userid = 3
AND    b.active = 1;
```